# How to display the same imageview1 in Activity1 from user select in Activity 2 imageview2?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is xml activity 1:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="143dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.098"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.952" />
```

This is java file of activity 1 where user select image in gallery phone and display it inside activity 1:

```
package com.example.ProPentest;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.provider.MediaStore;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.Spinner;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import java.io.IOException;

  public class form2 extends AppCompatActivity  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

  private static final String TAG = form2.class.getSimpleName();
  private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;


Button btn;
EditText et1, et2, et3, et4, et5;
String st, st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7;
Bitmap bmp;
Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
ImageView iv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form2);

    btn =findViewById( R.id.finish );
    et1=findViewById( R.id.editText2 );
    et2=findViewById( R.id.editText );
    et3=findViewById( R.id.assettext );
    et4=findViewById( R.id.et4 );
    et5=findViewById( R.id.et5 );
    sp1=findViewById( R.id.spinner );
    sp2=findViewById( R.id.spinner2 );
    sp3=findViewById( R.id.spinner3 );
    iv=findViewById( R.id.imageView );

    btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent( form2.this, display.class );
            st = et1.getText().toString();
            st1 = et2.getText().toString();
            st2 = et3.getText().toString();
            st3 = et4.getText().toString();
            st4 = et5.getText().toString();
            st5 = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            st6 = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            st7 = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            bmp = iv.getDrawingCache();
            i.putExtra( "Name", st );
            i.putExtra( "Date", st1 );
            i.putExtra( "Asset", st2 );
            i.putExtra( "Repro", st3 );
            i.putExtra( "Note", st4 );
            i.putExtra( "Spinner", st5 );
            i.putExtra( "Spinner2", st6 );
            i.putExtra( "Spinner3", st7 );
            i.putExtra( "imageView2", bmp );
            startActivity( i );
            finish();
        }});
            Button selectImage = findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);

            selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    chooseImage();
                }
            });
        }

        private void chooseImage() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
  PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

        }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition( position ).toString();
    Toast.makeText( parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && 
  data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

}
```

This is the xml activity2:

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="248dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/image_border"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp" />
```

This is java file of activity 2:

```
package com.example.ProPentest;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class display extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6, tv7, tv8;
String st, st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7;
Bitmap bmp;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_display );

    tv1 = findViewById( R.id.company_name );
    tv2 = findViewById( R.id.date );
    tv3 = findViewById( R.id.assettext );
    tv4 = findViewById( R.id.reprotext );
    tv5 = findViewById( R.id.notetext );
    tv6 = findViewById( R.id.basevultext );
    tv7 = findViewById( R.id.likelitext );
    tv8 = findViewById( R.id.priotext );
    iv = findViewById( R.id.imageView2 );

    st = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Name" );
    tv1.setText( st );
    st1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Date" );
    tv2.setText( st1 );
    st2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Asset" );
    tv3.setText( st2 );
    st3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Repro" );
    tv4.setText( st3 );
    st4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Note" );
    tv5.setText( st4 );
    st5 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Spinner" );
    tv6.setText( st5 );
    st6 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Spinner2" );
    tv7.setText( st6 );
    st7 = getIntent().getExtras().getString( "Spinner3" );
    tv8.setText( st7 );
    bmp = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("imageView2");
    iv.setImageBitmap( bmp );




}}
```

I tried to pass the imageview to the other's imageview2 activity2 but i result to white picture. I want the picture that user have selected from gallery phone pass from imageview1 to imageview2 inside another activity.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenerio pass `URI` to second activity using intent
the `URI` you are getting in `onActivityResult` method

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
```

and in second activity receive URI and set it to Imageview

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
```

Comment: thank you for the reply ...How can i make it user select image and the image display in imageview 1 and than only when user click on button NEXT to next activity , the same image will appear in the imageview 2?

Comment: The simplest way is save URI in global variable which you are getting in onactivityresult pass URI using Intent then in next activity in oCreate method convert URI to bitmap and set to imageview similarly you have done in activity one.